# Track a Google Analytics event that occurs when a user isn't on the site

Tags: events, google-analytics, analytics, offline, event-tracking

Our site enables users to send money to us via a bank transfer. They 'initiate' the transfer and get a reference code. Then they log in to their bank account and send the money using the reference code.

We track when a user promises to send the money but I'm not sure how to track when that money arrives. They won't be logged into the site when it happens which makes it complicated. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, GA works in the front end, i.e. browser (from Javascript). I would suggest you look at getting the reference code into a GA custom dimension at initiate time, then you can match the reference code you obtain from your bank with the GA one via Data Studio or Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to track events on behalf of a recent user, but it requires coding on server side. You need to use the [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/)
 to create this event, when you are notified about a successful transfer. You can send all relevant information to Google Analytics, like event category, action, or event value (e.g. transfer amount), or even track these as ecommerce transactions.

You can check the [parameter reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) to learn about the required and optional parameters to be sent with your hit. You can also experiment with such custom built hits with the [Hit Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) tool.

If you would like this event to be connected to your existing user, then you'll also need to store your visitor's client ID during their visit, and later reuse this client ID in your backend-initiated Analytics hit.

[Here is an example](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-111111-1&cid=storedClientID&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Ftransfer_success&ec=Transfer&ea=Success&ev=1000&ni=1) for an event hit for a recently stored ClientId, with given event attributes, including value.

There a few things to be considered in such scenarios, or at least to be aware of. Such events will generate additional hits in your Analytics property, and also initiate sessions, which can alter your various Analytics metrics, if their volume is comparable to your overall traffic.

Comment: Great thank you for this answer. We're already capturing a Custom_Client_ID so should be able to do this. I'll have a read up and try and implement it. Do you think it's possible to filter out the hits coming from the server in GA?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any default parameters in the queries, that could be used for this identification, but it's easy to define one. E.g. you can define filters based on request URL, event details, or even a custom dimension could be set up, if for any reason other values are not unique. You can specify a unique value in your server sourced hits, and set up a filter for this in GA.