# Excel Data to Google Analytics automation

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have excel sheet data coming from Bank everyday. I need to put this data in Google Analytics. I also have a valid hit. How do I automate excel data into Google Analytics through measurement protocol and app scripts? Not able to understand where measurement protocol come and app scripts

Comment: Google Apps Script is a javascript-based language used within the GSuite tools to create add-ons and automate some things. It seems like you want something that uses the Google APIs. I've made a suggested edit to your post to remove the google-apps-script tag.

Comment: suggested edit done. Thanks. To what I understand - I need to write a code in google sheet with app scripts - so this code will read my excel sheet everyday and then push data to Google Analytics, is it?

Comment: Do you need to join incoming data to existing hits (since you say "you have a valid hit"), or do you want to create hits from the data in your spreadsheet (which the reference to the measurement protocol would suggest)? The two are very different beasts.

Comment: The later one. Create hits from spreadsheet. Such as credit card approved, declined, in process -

Comment: You might find some good clues here. Nevertheless, you need to write your code to transform data in Sheets into Measurement protocoll parameters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54769301/track-a-google-analytics-event-that-occurs-when-a-user-isnt-on-the-site/54795811#54795811